# Can you get dot representation using 'list' command in LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I understand that by using `cons` we could have something like :

```
> (cons 'b 'c)
(B . C)
```

And that happens because the cell is split into two and the values are `B` and `C`.

My question is, can you get the same result using `list`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get `list` to return a dotted list, because ["*the last argument to `list` becomes the `car` of the last `cons` constructed*"](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_list_.htm) in the returned list.

But, you can get `list*` to return a dotted list. With the `list*` function, the final argument becomes the `cdr` of the last `cons`, so:

```
CL-USER> (list* 'a '(b))
(A B)
CL-USER> (list* 'a 'b '())
(A B)
CL-USER> (list* 'a 'b)
(A . B)
CL-USER> (list* 'a '(b c))
(A B C)
CL-USER> (list* 'a 'b '(c))
(A B C)
CL-USER> (list* 'a 'b 'c '())
(A B C)
CL-USER> (list* 'a 'b 'c)
(A B . C)
```

For example, `(list* 'a 'b 'c '())` and `(list 'a 'b 'c)` are both equivalent to:

```
CL-USER> (cons 'a (cons 'b (cons 'c '())))
(A B C)
```

But `(list* 'a 'b 'c)` is equivalent to:

```
CL-USER> (cons 'a (cons 'b 'c))
(A B . C)
```

And, `(list* 'a 'b)` is equivalent to:

```
CL-USER> (cons 'a 'b)
(A . B)
```

Answer (score 3):

No you can't, because a list is a list of cons cells whose last `cdr` is nil. The Lisp printer knows the convention and doesn't print a dot in that case.

```lisp
;; a cons cell
CL-USER> (cons 'b  'c)
(B . C)

[o|o]--- c
 |
 b

;; two cons cells, ending with a symbol: a dot.
CL-USER> (cons 'b  (cons 'c 'd))
(B C . D)

;; several cons cells, ending with a symbol: still a dot (at the last cons cell):
CL-USER> (cons 'b  (cons 'c (cons 'd (cons 'e 'f))))
(B C D E . F)

;; two cons cells, ending with nil: no dot.
CL-USER> (cons 'b  (cons 'c nil))
(B C)  ;; and not (B C . NIL)

[o|o]---[o|/]
 |       |
 b       c

;; with the list constructor:
CL-USER> (list 'b 'c)
(B C)
```

- https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/data-structures.html#building-lists-cons-cells-lists